# Java - SimpleDateFormat parses 12:19:00 to 00:19:00

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a string to date, but the output look incorrect:
Below is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){      
  Date startDate = new Date();      
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");

  try {
    startDate = (Date) formatter.parse("07.10.2012 12:19:24");
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  System.out.println("Formatted Date " + startDate.toString());
}
```

Program Output:
Formatted Date Sun Oct 07 **00**:19:24 IST 2012

Expected Output:
Formatted Date Sun Oct 07 **12**:19:24 IST 2012

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to use 24h format instead of 12h format...

> H     Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
>
> h     Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12

Yes, formatting characters are case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

The hh is for when you're doing am / pm, you need HH